# Why does IBM API Connect run differently in Bluemix than locally?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I just set up my local environment to use IBM API Connect and it gives me "extra options" to make the database. Now i'm using IBM API Connect inside IBM Bluemix and it doesn't have those "extra options" :/ I'd like to use it from IBM Bluemix to start migrating to the cloud, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the datasource connectors?

Comment: yes, i'm talking about that... here https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/getting-started/ at the last screenshot you can see 2 tabs "models" and "data sources" ... at bluemix i cant see those two tabs

Comment: The APIC Designer, which you run locally, helps define your models and connections, you then deploy that to Bluemix. You don't edit it on Bluemix itself.

Comment: oh! i see, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I said this in a comment, but it should be an answer...)

The APIC Designer, which you run locally, helps define your models and connections, you then deploy that to Bluemix. You don't edit it on Bluemix itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Local Developer toolkit gets installed on your computer for modeling and creating the api's through Strongloop or Kitura. After you have created your api's to run and publish them, bluemix publix cloud is used where you get a free developer portal and Node.js runtime environment for running your applications/micro-services.